# Best way to store references to .mp3 files with additional info, kept in mobile phone storage/external card

Tags: android, android-storage

I'm currently working on audiobook player application I and I'm thinking about how to keep references to audiobook files.

So far I let user specify folder where books are kept and recognize subfolders / particular books.

Now I need to store those references. Audiobooks are always released in many parts, so lets say we have a 'Season of Storms' book and we have like 20 parts of that book: seasonofstorms-part1, seasonofstorms-part2 and so on.

I need to keep them linked to particular book and I need some more additional information stored, like what is name of the part that user finished listening to, and what is the time this part should start while opening book again.

So I though it could fit nicely in some JSON schema. I could make POJOs like:

- Show with fields: name and List parts,
- Part with fields: status [finished, notStarted, inProgress], time.

After resuming listening to a book application would search for part with 'inProgress' status and start playing at 'time'. I could parse these POJOs to JSON and keep them in SharedPreferences. What do you thing of this approach? Some better options? How could I make this work in any other way and what is the best approach in your opinion?